# Get target audiences of a user/group via API

Tags: google-workspace

Is there a way to get a user's target audiences, or the other way around, to get the users/groups of a given target audience via API?

Can't find any documentation. Target audience shows up when listing Drive Documents, now I need to do it from the users to make the match.